# How to animate walking person with css keyframes with inline SVG?

Tags: css, animation

I have studied the [walking man](https://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/aNxEBg?editors=1100) and they use a background-image. Can I reproduce a walk cycle with inline SVG image? This is my [pen](https://codepen.io/hellomev/pen/QWbXooG).

CSS

```
@keyframes stroll {
  from { transform: translateX(-100%); }
  to { transform: translateX(500%); }
}
#walk-container {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 30%; 
    vertical-align: middle; 
    overflow: hidden; 
  animation: stroll 30s linear infinite;
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by inline svg image?

Comment: @Manjuboyz : ie. Not a background like in the walking man example.

Comment: you can have the svg frames defined separately and use steps in css animation to switch each frame

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: We don't need the whole codebase...just enough to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: @Paulie_D : That's the purpose of codepen, to work and share work.

Comment: Nope. SO requires the code actually in the question not on a separate site.